# Trigger classList for * in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is possible to trigger the `*` css element by using classList or something similar in JavaScript?

In my CSS I wrote following to disable **all** CSS animations site-wide:

```
* {
    transition: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
}
```

This works fine, but I want to trigger it by JavaScript, so I can enable or disable the animations.

I've done following:

```
*.animationsDisabled {
    transition: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
}
```

And at the end of my HTML document (inside the `<body>`), I wrote:

```
<script>
    document.body.classList.add('animationsDisabled');
</script>
```

It seems that when I load the page, Chrome recognizes what I've done, showing it in the CSS of the developer section, but all CSS animations still work.

[image: element]

Why won't this work and what can I make that this works?
(Without jQuery, if possible)

Comment: am i the only one here who thinks that JQuery is beautiful one? :)

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş I know, jQuery is shorter, but then the page needs to load the entire jQuery Extension, which is 80kb or so. I want to safe as much bandwidth as possible.

Comment: `*.animationsDisabled` targets any element that *has* the css class `animationsDisabled`.

Comment: Would it not be better to add the `animationsDisabled` class to the `body` and then use a selector like `.animationsDisabled * {...}`? And if your setting doesn't work then see if the specificity is more than the other selector which is adding the animation.

Comment: _“Why won't this work”_ – because you are only disabling it for the body element, because you only set the class on that one. `*` still matches all other elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*.animationsDisabled` targets any element that *has* the css class `animationsDisabled`.  Please also note that `*.cssClass` is functionally identical to `.cssClass` as a css selector.

What you want instead is

```
.animationsDisabled * { 
  transition-property: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
}
```

which targets any element that is a descendant to an element with css class `animationsDisabled`.

Edit: Please check that any element inside your body has these rules in the inspector:

[image]

If these rules are not visible in the inspector, you have not applied the CSS correctly as suggested in this answer (or the answer below).

Comment: And how do I call it? `document.body.classList.add('animationsDisabled');` won't call it.

Comment: @Fusseldieb: Your call seems perfect. All you need to do is add the class to `body`. If you attach the class to `body`, the selector provided in answer will select all elements under `body` when it has this class. Like I said in my comment earlier, if it still doesn't work check the specificity of other selectors.

Comment: What do you mean "call"? Setting the `animationsDisabled` class on the body in combination with the css suggested will do what you described.

Comment: Setting the classList to the body, like I said in my first comment here, doensn't do anything..

Comment: Did you change your CSS according to my answer?

Comment: Yes, rechecked and it won't work. http://prntscr.com/cx2jep - http://prntscr.com/cx2jm5 - http://prntscr.com/cx2jp6

Comment: It doesn't. The screenshots are there... Chrome says the body has the class, but... it won't work.

Comment: Please click any element inside the body so the inspector shows the css rules for that element. Check that your disabling rules are applied.

Comment: The CSS you use for disabling only "disables" `transition-property`, not the shorthand property `transition`. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Added `transition-property` to CSS... Still animations. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/cx2v3b

Comment: You obviously have not applied the css as suggested in the answer. Otherwise it'd be visible in the inspector.

Comment: It worked! I was suspecting that my css-minify was causing the problem - and in fact - it was. It removed the spaces between the class and *. It showed up this way: `.animationsDisabled*`. Thanks for your patience and help. Now the animations are controllable.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the wrong point. To disable the animations you need to use

```
body.animationsDisabled * {
    -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
            transform: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
            animation: none !important;     
}
```

then by removing the class you should be able to get animations back.

**edit:** if you are also animating the `body`, the classname should be:

```
body.animationsDisabled, body.animationsDisabled * { }
```

```js
function toggleAnim()
{
  if(hasClass(document.body,"animationsDisabled")) {
     removeClass(document.body,"animationsDisabled");
  } else {
    addClass(document.body,"animationsDisabled");
  }
}

function hasClass(ele, cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
}
function addClass(ele, cls) {
    if (!hasClass(ele, cls)) ele.className += " " + cls;
}
function removeClass(ele, cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele, cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
        ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
}
```

```css
body.animationsDisabled * {
    transition-property: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation: animation 500ms linear infinite both;
  animation: animation 500ms linear infinite both;
  transform-origin: 30px 41px 0px;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  0.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.981, 0.216, 0, 0, -0.031, 1.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.981, 0.216, 0, 0, -0.031, 1.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.28% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.941, 0.359, 0, 0, -0.134, 0.998, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.941, 0.359, 0, 0, -0.134, 0.998, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  2.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.846, 0.538, 0, 0, -0.407, 0.917, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.846, 0.538, 0, 0, -0.407, 0.917, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.78% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.737, 0.676, 0, 0, -0.64, 0.769, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.737, 0.676, 0, 0, -0.64, 0.769, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.3% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.683, 0.73, 0, 0, -0.715, 0.699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.683, 0.73, 0, 0, -0.715, 0.699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.05% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.6, 0.8, 0, 0, -0.801, 0.599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.6, 0.8, 0, 0, -0.801, 0.599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  6.29% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.449, 0.893, 0, 0, -0.898, 0.439, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.449, 0.893, 0, 0, -0.898, 0.439, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.191, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.982, 0.188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.191, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.982, 0.188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  11.29% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.082, 0.997, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.082, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.082, 0.997, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.082, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.3% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.144, 0.99, 0, 0, -0.99, -0.144, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.144, 0.99, 0, 0, -0.99, -0.144, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  17.22% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.146, 0.989, 0, 0, -0.989, -0.146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.146, 0.989, 0, 0, -0.989, -0.146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.13, 0.991, 0, 0, -0.991, -0.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.13, 0.991, 0, 0, -0.991, -0.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  28.33% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.032, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.032, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  39.44% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  61.66% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  83.98% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}

@keyframes animation { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  0.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.981, 0.216, 0, 0, -0.031, 1.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.981, 0.216, 0, 0, -0.031, 1.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.28% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.941, 0.359, 0, 0, -0.134, 0.998, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.941, 0.359, 0, 0, -0.134, 0.998, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  2.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.846, 0.538, 0, 0, -0.407, 0.917, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.846, 0.538, 0, 0, -0.407, 0.917, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.78% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.737, 0.676, 0, 0, -0.64, 0.769, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.737, 0.676, 0, 0, -0.64, 0.769, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.3% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.683, 0.73, 0, 0, -0.715, 0.699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.683, 0.73, 0, 0, -0.715, 0.699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.05% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.6, 0.8, 0, 0, -0.801, 0.599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.6, 0.8, 0, 0, -0.801, 0.599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  6.29% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.449, 0.893, 0, 0, -0.898, 0.439, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.449, 0.893, 0, 0, -0.898, 0.439, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.191, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.982, 0.188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.191, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.982, 0.188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  11.29% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.082, 0.997, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.082, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.082, 0.997, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.082, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.3% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.144, 0.99, 0, 0, -0.99, -0.144, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.144, 0.99, 0, 0, -0.99, -0.144, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  17.22% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.146, 0.989, 0, 0, -0.989, -0.146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.146, 0.989, 0, 0, -0.989, -0.146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.13, 0.991, 0, 0, -0.991, -0.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.13, 0.991, 0, 0, -0.991, -0.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  28.33% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.032, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.032, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  39.44% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.01, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  61.66% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  83.98% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}
```

```html
<body class="">
  <div class="animated">
    
  </div>
  <button id="test" onclick="toggleAnim()">Test Animation</button>
</body>
```

Comment: No need to specify the body in the selector.

Comment: Being specific is valuable sometimes.

Comment: did you add this class to your body?

Comment: do you see the class there when you inspect the body?

Comment: Oh, now I saw it... But it doesn't work... I think it adds the class only to the body css, without going through other objects

Comment: Which is exactly what it should do.

Comment: It should stop all CSS animations on the whole site... When I add the `*` directly, it works, with JavaScript it doesn't.

Comment: here is the snippet I wrote. Test it.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but... here it won't work, no matter what. Here your implementation: http://prntscr.com/cx2paq

Comment: I added prefixes in case you are using a prefixed one.

Comment: There are no other solutions then until you've given us something else to work on. We are simply guessing the solution here. If you provide us some HTML, then we can help more. This is working as you see in the snippet.

Comment: I even added a `setTimeout` to trigger the script. It triggers, because i saw that Chrome flashed the body class part shortly. It **is** applying, but... I have no clue..

Comment: IT WORKED! The problem was that my php script to minify the css, replaced ´.animationsDisabled *´ with ´.animationsDisabled*´. :)

Comment: @TahaPaksu Nice example!

Comment: Thanks very much mate :)

Comment: @TahaPaksu Thanks for your patience and help too :)